ERROR: Model Failed File Verification in OpenUBA
I have attempted to run the OpenUBA backend Python code, but each time I try to start the server i.e. by running the make command in the Linux terminal, I encounter the following error.


2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO is_installed: model_test
2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO is_installed(): __init__.py
2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO is_installed(): MODEL.py
2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO Model Session, model [IS] installed: model_test
2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] WARNING Computed Component file hash: 09c88336687a299bf761219ac72c93ecb4f65d51247761b063208d3cc2338d91
2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] WARNING Computed Component file hash: 8402bc576c2fd1830e7098609616343debfca51d611066696afa30fde4d4318f
2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] ERROR Model Failed File Verification: {'model_name': 'model_test', 'description': 'blank', 'mitre_tactic': '', 'mitre_technique_name': '', 'mitre_technique_id': 'T1010', 'enabled': True, 'root': 'ANJKD8aioh8wonsLAS9HWOI', 'return': {'return_type': 'user_risks', 'artifacts': []}, 'score': 10, 'model_context': {}, 'components': [{'type': 'external', 'filename': '__init__.py', 'data_hash': 'bb359488ff009930fdb409b2e37d2770fa302e249aae9fb277ed56a04f1ce750', 'file_hash': '8856500188054fcfc51011fbc57bd667b8f9a70d58b5ce40d4ca3ade9b5caac6', 'file_payload': 'IyBuZWVkIHRvIGltcG9ydCAuTU9ERUwKZnJvbSAuTU9ERUwgaW1wb3J0IGV4ZWN1dGUK'}, {'type': 'external', 'filename': 'MODEL.py', 'data_hash': 'c91569ef18120310e433645d54eaddc4fa72bf5a0613a1e13a3e75d2abda665f', 'file_hash': '585a2c07d4644acb0da61202490cafb99a58570dc9861b14426576f54350fdc6', 'file_payload': 'IyBuZWVkIHRvIGV4cG9zZSBleGVjdXRlCmRlZiBleGVjdXRlKCk6CglwcmludCgibW9kZWxfdGVzdCB0ZXN0aW5nLi4uIikKCXJldHVybl9vYmplY3Q6IGRpY3QgPSB7fQoKCWZvciB4IGluIHJhbmdlKDAsMTAwMDAwKToKCQlyZXR1cm5fb2JqZWN0W3hdID0gewoJCQkidmFsdWUiOiAidGVzdCIKCQl9CgoJcHJpbnQoIm1vZGVsIGVuZCBydW4uLiIpCglyZXR1cm4gcmV0dXJuX29iamVjdAo='}]}
2024-09-25 02:36:47 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] WARNING Model Result is empty: model_test


2024-09-25 02:36:44 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO is_installed: model_1
2024-09-25 02:36:44 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO is_installed(): __init__.py
2024-09-25 02:36:44 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO is_installed(): MODEL.py
2024-09-25 02:36:44 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO Model Session, model [IS] installed: model_1
2024-09-25 02:36:44 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] WARNING Computed Component file hash: 09c88336687a299bf761219ac72c93ecb4f65d51247761b063208d3cc2338d91
2024-09-25 02:36:45 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] WARNING Computed Component file hash: e5b9956e58768565e0c64cb89ee3d0be2cd5f6d245645a131a0c93cf80388783
2024-09-25 02:36:45 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] ERROR Model Failed File Verification: {'model_name': 'model_1', 'description': 'blank', 'mitre_tactic': '', 'mitre_technique_name': '', 'mitre_technique_id': 'T1010', 'enabled': True, 'root': 'ANJKD8aioh8wonsLAS9HWOI', 'return': {'return_type': 'user_risks', 'artifacts': []}, 'score': 10, 'model_context': {}, 'components': [{'type': 'external', 'filename': '__init__.py', 'data_hash': 'bb359488ff009930fdb409b2e37d2770fa302e249aae9fb277ed56a04f1ce750', 'file_hash': '8856500188054fcfc51011fbc57bd667b8f9a70d58b5ce40d4ca3ade9b5caac6', 'file_payload': 'IyBuZWVkIHRvIGltcG9ydCAuTU9ERUwKZnJvbSAuTU9ERUwgaW1wb3J0IGV4ZWN1dGUK'}, {'type': 'external', 'filename': 'MODEL.py', 'data_hash': '7abf09221bf1a1991a0044a2b8a649a440176bbfb0f95be4ab4d54d87a605413', 'file_hash': 'b017478eb77b119515217bb2535ef1727ddac6a3298e86a9f1eb1dbe3e1d80e4', 'file_payload': 'ZnJvbSBtb2RlbF9tb2R1bGVzIGltcG9ydCB0ZXN0X21vZHVsZQoKIyBuZWVkIHRvIGV4cG9zZSBleGVjdXRlCmRlZiBleGVjdXRlKCk6CiAgICBwcmludCgibW9kZWxfdGVzdCB0ZXN0aW5nLi4uIGJlZm9yZSBkaXNrIikKICAgIHJldHVybl9vYmplY3Q6IGRpY3QgPSBkaWN0KCkKICAgIHRlc3RfbW9kdWxlLkV4ZWN1dGUoKQogICAgZm9yIHggaW4gcmFuZ2UoMCwxMDAwMDApOgogICAgICAgIHJldHVybl9vYmplY3RbeF0gPSB7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICJ2YWx1ZSI6ICJ0ZXN0IgogICAgICAgIH0KCiAgICBwcmludCgibW9kZWwgZW5kIHJ1bi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uLiIpCiAgICByZXR1cm4gcmV0dXJuX29iamVjdAo='}]}

2024-09-25 02:36:45 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] WARNING Model Result is empty: model_1
2024-09-25 02:36:45 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO dataset session
2024-09-25 02:36:45 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO Dataset_Session: read_es_index
2024-09-25 02:36:45 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] INFO Reading ES index
2024-09-25 02:36:45 DESKTOP-T7MAB6U root[6812] ERROR Error inside ES.read(): HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=62000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb11ad6f510>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

After cloing the OpenUBA repo (https://github.com/GACWR/OpenUBA), I installed the python libraries. When I ran the python backend code, I got the errors as explained above.
Environment:
OS: WSL Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Python version: Python 3.7.17
Issue: Despite following the setup instructions as per the documentation, I keep encountering the above errors. I have not made any modifications to the original code.
Could anyone kindly guide me on how to resolve this issue?
